# I have a error after pointing RStudio to Microsft Open R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a error after pointing RStudio IDE to the R language of Microsoft (Microsoft R Open 4.0.2)

```
error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.0/lib64/R/lib/microsoft-r-cacert.pem
  CApath: none
```

I think I need to do some export in some environment variable to the CAfile but I don't know how.
All that is in Linux-Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: The issue was a while ago and I can't remember well the issue. But the context was trying to calculate a statistic (VaR) for my graduate work.My RStudio has registered Microsoft R Open, but to calculate that statistic I needed the canon standard R; so, I tried to change that and I couldn't, with the above as one of the errors. Finally, after checking with my Professeur I didn't need to calculate that statistic and could keep Microsoft R Open. So, I never checked that error any more.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by updating curl in RStudio:

`install.packages('curl')`.

It appears that the version of `curl` shipped with MRO 4.0.2 was actually built against R 4.0.0, so it looks for `microsoft-r-cacert.pem` in the wrong place.

No amount of environment variable setting or passing options to `curl` got it to look for the root certificate bundle in the right place.